# Submit a form only if a checkbox is checked

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, checkbox

I want to submit a form only if a checkbox is checked (as opposed to submit a form via the checkbox)

I don't need to save the checking of the checkbox. It is similar to "I agree to EULA bla bla"

Prefer not using javascript for this

thanks

Comment: I see 2 options: submit, and prove if checkbox is checked, render again same form with validation error; use java script to disable the submit button if the checkbox is not checked. Who should implement the code that does the not-submitting (we have a HTML form, no ruby code in the browser)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue using a `validates :terms_of_service, :acceptance => true` in the model and adding a checkbox in the form block.

That solved that issue quick and easy.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if checkbox is checked or not using code like this:

```
var chkbox = document.getElementById('checkboxID');

if (chkbox.checked === true){
  // it is checked, submit form
}
else {
  // it is not checked, dont submit form
}
```

Comment: can I incorporated this script inside the form block?

Comment: @RailsN00b: What do you mean by form block ?